# SpecFlow MonoDevelop 5.10

Tags: monodevelop, specflow

For a project I need to develop a C# application on linux.
I have installed MonoDevelop 5.10 on linux mint 18.0.

I try to install the SpecFlow addins from this link:
http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/4

but they are out of date.

I also try to create a class library project and add the nuget package specFlow,
but when I try to add a feature file to the project the wizard do not offer me SpecFlow Template.

Any suggestion

Comment: `Adding` `.MPack` for 5.x and 6.x are located here: https://github.com/mikeyjones/SpecFlow (consult the realm for URLs)

Comment: Sorry, but I m not sure what you mean

Comment: Read the README at https://github.com/mikeyjones/SpecFlow